# react bootstrap accordion dynamic data collapsing does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

In react bootstrap, i am using accordion here hardcode data working finer, if i implemented dynamic data not working, (ex) first panel open, if i click second panel then first panel does not closed, and ****[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgK8r.png)if panel open need to change tile color****

```
class CollapseContentComponent extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
<div className="collapsecontent-component">
<Accordion>
<Panel header={this.props.collapseTitle} eventKey={this.props.collapsemainKey}>
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.collapseBody }}></div>
</Panel>
</Accordion>
</div>
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Controlled PanelGroups https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/panel/#panels-controlled, So you don't need to manage opening and closing of others.

```
      <PanelGroup
        accordion
        id="accordion-controlled-example"
        activeKey={this.state.activeKey}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
      >
        <Panel eventKey="1">
          <Panel.Heading>
            <Panel.Title toggle>Panel heading 1</Panel.Title>
          </Panel.Heading>
          <Panel.Body collapsible>Panel content 1</Panel.Body>
        </Panel>
        <Panel eventKey="2">
          <Panel.Heading>
            <Panel.Title toggle>Panel heading 2</Panel.Title>
          </Panel.Heading>
          <Panel.Body collapsible>Panel content 2</Panel.Body>
        </Panel>
      </PanelGroup>
```

Comment: If i using above method i got error like     :    Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `CommonHelpCollapseContentComponent`.

Comment: <div>
      <PanelGroup
        accordion
        id="accordion-controlled-example"
        activeKey={this.state.activeKey}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
      >
        <Panel eventKey="1">
          <Panel.Heading>
            <Panel.Title toggle>Panel heading 1</Panel.Title>
          </Panel.Heading>
          <Panel.Body collapsible>Panel content 1</Panel.Body>
        </Panel>
      </PanelGroup>
    </div>

Comment: The above link archive, So https://web.archive.org/components/panel/